# Refer to a property from inside the class itself

Tags: python

Say I have a class that looks like

```
class MeasurementList:

  def __init__(self, measurement_list):
    self.__measurements = measurement_list

  @property
  def measurements(self):
    return self.__measurements
```

what is the most pythonic way to retrieve the value of `self.measurements` from inside the class; directly accessing the variable or going via the property (external accessor)? I.e.,

```
def do_something(self)
  # do something
  return self.measurements
```

or

```
def do_something(self)
  # do something
  return self.__measurements
```

Does any of the alternatives have any speed advantages, or easier refactoring, or other factors?

Comment: How about just `class MeasurementList(collections.namedtuple('MeasurementList', ('measurements',))):` and forget the `@property`?

Comment: I believe you meant `return self.__measurements` in the `@property` definition.

Comment: Shouldn't your `measurements()` method be returning `self.__measurements`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of properties is to add additional functionality to the process of getting/setting a field, while keeping the interface of a field.

That means you start out with a simple field, and access it as a field:

```
class MeasurementList:

  def __init__(self, measurement_list):
    self.measurements = measurement_list


  def foo(self):
     print("there are %d measurements" % len(self.measurements))
```

Then if you want/have to add additional logic to the setter/getter you convert it into a property, without having changed the interface. Thus no need to refactor accessing code.

```
class MeasurementList:

  def __init__(self, measurement_list):
    self._count = 0
    self.measurements = measurement_list

  @property
  def measurements(self):
    return self._measurements

  @measurements.setter
  def measurements(self value):
     self._measurements = value
     self._count = len(value)

  def foo(self):
    print("there are %d measurements" % (self._count))

 def bar(self):
   print(self.measurements)
```

Alternative reasons for using properties are readonly properties or properties that return computed (not directly stored in fields) values. In the case of read only properties you would access the backing field directly to write (from inside the class).

```
class MeasurementList:

  def __init__(self, measurement_list):
    self._measurements = measurement_list

  # readonly
  @property
  def measurements(self):
    return self._measurements

  # computed property
  @property
  def count(self):
    return len(self.measurements)

  def foo(self):
    print("there are %d measurements" % (self.count))

  def bar(self):
    print(self.measurements)
```

Keeping all that in mind you should not forget that there is no such thing as 'private' in python. If anyone really wants to access a private anything he can do so. It is just convention that anything starting with an underscore should be considered private and not be accessed by the caller. That is also the reason why one underscore is enough. Two underscores initiate some name mangling that is primarily used to avoid name conflicts, not prohibit access.

Answer (score 3):

When you use properties in Python, you should almost always avoid accessing attribute under the property, unless it's necessary. Why?

Properties in Python are used to create getter, setter and deleter, but you probably know it.
They are usually used when you process the property data during those operation. I don't really have a good example for it right now, but consider following:

```
class User:
    # _password stores hash object from user's password.
    @property
    def password(self):
        return self._password.hexdigest() # Returns hash as string

    @password.setter
    def password(self, val):
        self._password = hash(val) # Creates hash object
```

Here using `_password` and `password` results in quite different output. In most cases, you need simply `password`, both inside and outside class definition, unless you want to interact directly with object wrapped by it.

If you have the same object returned in getter and attribute, then you should follow the same practice, as you may wish sameday to add some checks or mechanics to it, and it will save you from refactoring every use of `_attribute`, and following that convention will also save you from errors when creating more complex descriptors.

Also, from your code, note that using `__measurements` (leading double underscore) results in name mangling of attribute name, so if you ever inherit from `MeasurementList`, you will be almost unable to access this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you have seen code like this in Java. It is, however, deeply unpythonic to use methods where attribute access serves the purpose perfectly well. Your existing code would be much more simply written as

class MeasurementList:

```
   def __init__(self, measurement_list):
       self.measurements = measurement_list
```

Then no property is required.

The point is, presumably, to avoid allowing code external to the class to alter the value of the `__measurements` attribute. How necessary is this in practice?

Comment: I think the question is really: Is it Pythonic to use external accessors to refer to internal data? It's not really about attributes.

Comment: You assume correctly, the intention was to make the class interface as small as possible, so that it would be perfectly clear that `self.measurements` should not be changed outside of the constructor. I'm basically trying to minimize the complexity of using the class. Is this wrong? (not asked sarcastically)

Comment: It isn't wrong, but if done gratuitously it will increase the complexity of your code for no good reason. Your example code (presumably after the suggested correction to have the property return `self.__measurements`) works fine for the purpose you state (i.e. to provide a read-only `measurements` property.

In cases where a property really IS necessary (because computation is required) you should always use the property. Since you have defined it, it would be counter-productive to then refer to the `__measurements` attribute directly: what happens if you add computation to the property?

Comment: Thanks @holdenweb, edited based on your comment before you edited. (this is like some kind of edit war now)

Answer (score 0):

Use setters and getters **both** inside and outside your class. It would make your code easier to maintain once you add some additional data processing into setters and getters:

```
class C(object):
    _p = 1

    @property
    def p(self):
        print 'getter'
        return self._p

    @p.setter
    def p(self, val):
        print 'setter'
        self._p = val

    def any_method(self):
        self.p = 5
        print '----'
        a = self.p

myObject = C()
myObject.any_method()
```

From the output, you see that setter and getter are invoked:

```
setter
----
getter
```

Comment: Remove the `print` statements from the property, however, and the need for it goes away completely. Properties should not be used simply as a substitution for read/write attribute access, a technique most favored by Java programmers but completely unnecessary in Python. So I presume this was simply an illustrative example.

Comment: In this particular code - yes. However, if you create setter and getter it usually means that there are some additional checks. You'd better perform these check ups both inside and outside your class.

Comment: Correct, as stated above

Comment: Anyway, your reply is very nice, that's why I upvoted it. Agree with you